# How to include credentials in dockerfile from clause

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am new to Docker.
I cloned the GitHub project and trying to create the image by running:

```
docker build -t imagename .
```

But its giving an error:

```
username@LAPTOP-MMMMBU:~/myfolder/test$ docker build -t newimage .
[+] Building 10.8s (3/3) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for registry.abcd.org/test:base                                            10.8s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for registry.abcd.org/test:base:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: unexpected status code [manifests base]: 401 Unauthorized
```

Where to insert the credentials here (user/password).

Please help.

Comment: What is wrong in the question..? why is it downgraded - my jenkins pipeline runs somewhere I have little control. what will I do with docker login in my local ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you can authenticate to the docker registry where you are pulling your base image, you can run `docker login registry.abcd.org`, and enter your username and password when prompted.  Your subsequent build command will then be able to pull the image.

```
docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/